Openstreetmap: Overpass QL query to get all house numbers and streets of a city with coordinates
I'm using the following query to try to get all house numbers and streets of a city with coordinates. The query gives my zero results. What I'm doing wrong?
[out:csv(::lat, ::lon, "addr:street", "addr:housenumber"; true; ",")];
area[name="Bolzano"]->.searchArea;
(
  node(area.searchArea)["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"];
);
out center;


The main issue was about not using geocoding to search the area.
Try with the following :
[out:csv(::lat, ::lon, "addr:street", "addr:housenumber"; true; ",")];
// fetch area "Bolzano" to search in
{{geocodeArea:Bolzano}}->.searchArea;
(
  node(area.searchArea)["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"];
);
out center;

